# How do I use Python with a database?

Tags: python, database

I wrote a Python program that handles very large data. As it processes the data, it puts the processed data into an array, which easily grows to hundreds of megabytes or even over a gigabyte.

The reason I set it like that is because Python needs to continuously access the data in the array. Because the array gets larger and larger, the process is easily prone to error and very slow.

Is there a way to have the array-like database stored on a different file or database module and access it on a as-needed basis?

Perhaps this is a very basic task, but I have no clue.

Comment: How often are you accessing this data? Is it linear access? Random access?

Comment: Just for the sake of interest, how much RAM does the program consume at peak levels?

Comment: @ubik it's linear in the first phase and random in the second phase. It builds an array from analyzing the data, and array gets larger as more data are processed, which is done linearly. Later, the values in the array are continuously and randomly accessed for computing other values.

Comment: @MorganWilde it pretty much stopped at about 600MB

Comment: giga bytes of data in an array?. seriously you should consider to use a database. simple mysql table will do.

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc, you may want to look into the `mmap` module for the second phase. 600MB can easily fit in memory and `mmap` can be pretty effective then.

Comment: @ubik I'm in a testing stage, but later I will need about 10GB of data or more. Would mmap still work? or should I turn to sql?

Comment: @thavan, I disagree. If all OP needs is a simple linear structure, a relational DB can be an overkill.

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc it depends on the structure of your data and the memory you have available. If you don't need to keep the intermediate values anywhere, why even bother writing them to disk?

Comment: @ubik I need to cache the value, compute with it, and write the computed value back to the array. I do need the intermediate values.

Comment: @ubik If I write it to disk, say to a text file, can I still access it like I access a value in an array?

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc no, not as easily. Maybe you should have a look into some lightweight DB/cache solutions such as Redis/memcached and SQLite.

Comment: @ubik I think I'll look deeper into your suggested tools. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) if you want. it is part of the python
   packages, it is simpler for basic usage.
2. [MySQL for python](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/)
3. [Postgres for python](http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqlpythontutorial/)

Comment: I recommend you sqlite3 too.